# Google C++ code example explanation, translating to C#

Tags: c#, c++

I'm working with the Google DoubleClick ad exchange API. Their examples are in C++ and well, I'm pretty awful at C++. I'm trying to convert this to C# for something I'm working on and really, I think I just need some explanation of what is actually happening in certain blocks of [this](https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/rtb/response-guide/decrypt-hyperlocal) code sample. Honestly I kind of know what should happen over all but I'm not sure I am getting it 'right' and with encryption/decryption there isn't a 'sort of right'.

This is the full example from their API site:

```
bool DecryptByteArray(
    const string& ciphertext, const string& encryption_key,
    const string& integrity_key, string* cleartext) {
  // Step 1. find the length of initialization vector and clear text.
  const int cleartext_length =
     ciphertext.size() - kInitializationVectorSize - kSignatureSize;
  if (cleartext_length < 0) {
    // The length can't be correct.
    return false;
  }

  string iv(ciphertext, 0, kInitializationVectorSize);

  // Step 2. recover clear text
  cleartext->resize(cleartext_length, '\0');
  const char* ciphertext_begin = string_as_array(ciphertext) + iv.size();
  const char* const ciphertext_end = ciphertext_begin + cleartext->size();
  string::iterator cleartext_begin = cleartext->begin();

  bool add_iv_counter_byte = true;
  while (ciphertext_begin < ciphertext_end) {
    uint32 pad_size = kHashOutputSize;
    uchar encryption_pad[kHashOutputSize];

    if (!HMAC(EVP_sha1(), string_as_array(encryption_key),
              encryption_key.length(), (uchar*)string_as_array(iv),
              iv.size(), encryption_pad, &pad_size)) {
      printf("Error: encryption HMAC failed.\n");
      return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0;
         i < kBlockSize && ciphertext_begin < ciphertext_end;
         ++i, ++cleartext_begin, ++ciphertext_begin) {
      *cleartext_begin = *ciphertext_begin ^ encryption_pad[i];
    }

    if (!add_iv_counter_byte) {
      char& last_byte = *iv.rbegin();
      ++last_byte;
      if (last_byte == '\0') {
        add_iv_counter_byte = true;
      }
    }

    if (add_iv_counter_byte) {
      add_iv_counter_byte = false;
      iv.push_back('\0');
    }
  }
```

Step 1 is quite obvious. This block is what I am really not sure how to interpret:

```
if (!HMAC(EVP_sha1(), string_as_array(encryption_key),
          encryption_key.length(), (uchar*)string_as_array(iv),
          iv.size(), encryption_pad, &pad_size)) {
  printf("Error: encryption HMAC failed.\n");
  return false;
}
```

What exactly is happening in that if body? What would that look like in C#? There are a lot of parameters that do SOMETHING but it seems like an awful lot crammed in a small spot. Is there some stdlib HMAC class? If I knew more about that I might better understand what's happening.

Comment: There will be a function/macro called `HMAC` somewhere that will tell you what this is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent C# code for that block is:

```
using (var hmac = new HMACSHA1(encryption_key))
{
    var encryption_pad = hmac.ComputeHash(iv);
}
```

It's computing the SHA1 HMAC of the initialization vector (IV), using the given encryption key.

The `HMAC` function is actually [a macro from OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/hmac.html).

Just as a comment, I think it would be easier to implement this from their pseudocode description rather than from their C++ code.

Comment: Absolutely agree. I have made the attempt but I was debugging it and was hoping for a revelation by examining the C++ code. That was the one block that had me largely unsure if there was some magic that wasn't obvious to a person not fluent in C++. I'll see how this matches up against what I have.